# What is the meaning of free variables?

Tags: logic, symbolic-logic

In some books I see something like: phi(x<sub>1</sub>,...,x<sub>n</sub>) with free variables among x<sub>1</sub>,...,x<sub>n</sub>.

An example of this is on 2nd paragraph, page 25 of the book [Knowledge in Action](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/knowledge-action). I have included a snapshot of this page:

[image]

Does this mean all the free variables are only in x<sub>1</sub>,...,x<sub>n</sub> and perhaps some of x<sub>1</sub>,...,x<sub>n</sub> are not free? Then this would indicate some of them are bound, but I do not see a quantifier.

Could you please help in clarifying this point?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Philosophy SE. Notational conventions vary, so please point out specific book and page where this is used and/or provide an extended quote. Some of xi might be specified as constants in the text, and some as variables. This happens when [instantiation rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_generalization) are used to remove quantifiers, for example.

Comment: Hi, thank you. I have edited my question to include a specific reference to a book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how the [*forallx*](http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/forallxyyc.pdf) text describes free and bound variables (page 223, section 26.3):

> A **bound variable** is an occurrence of a variable x that
>   is within the scope of either ∀x or ∃x.
>
> A **free variable** is any occurrence of a variable that is not
>   bound.

As an example to illustrate bound and free variables and the scope of quantifiers, they provide the following

> ∀x(E(x) ∨ D(y)) → ∃z(E(x) → L(z, x))
>
> The scope of the universal quantifier ‘∀x’ is ‘∀x(E(x) ∨ D(y))’,
>   so the first ‘x’ is bound by the universal quantifier. However, the
>   second and third occurrence of ‘x’ are free. Equally, the ‘y’ is free.
>   The scope of the existential quantifier ‘∃z’ is ‘(E(x) → L(z, x))’,
>   so ‘z’ is bound.

Note how the ‘x’ is free in the consequent, but bound in the antecedent. Furthermore formulas need not be sentences in the context of the *forallx* text:

> A **sentence** of FOL is any formula of FOL that contains
>   no free variables.

It is important to be aware of the definitions of the logic text you are using and when reading a different text to note any differences one might find.

---

P. D. Magnus, Tim Button with additions by J. Robert Loftis remixed and revised by Aaron Thomas-Bolduc, Richard Zach, forallx Calgary Remix: An Introduction to Formal Logic, Fall 2019. http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/forallxyyc.pdf

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation! I have edited my question and added a reference to a book.

Comment: I don't have Reiter's book. I wonder if you could quote the relevant part of the 2nd paragraph on page 25.@Fabiana

Comment: I added a snapshot. I hope it is clear

Comment: @Fabiana Unless "free" means something other than what I'm expecting from my answer, I would assume they are all free because they do not have quantifiers to bind them.